# How to continuously draw a Sin function on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, continuous, curves

I want to draw a wave based on the sin function that is drawn continuously over time. By that I mean that the wave will be sliding off to the left disappearing off the left side of the screen, and at the same time I will be adding to it in the center of the screen so that it simply continues forever, undulating up and down. The point of this is a neat / educational demonstration of the sin function.

I know how to draw quadratic and bezier curves, but the methods provided simply draw the curves all at once. There is no smooth progression, which is what I need.

I thought of simply spawning particles in the center of the screen at a vertical offset based on the sin function and having the particles move to the left at a constant velocity. But constantly spawning particles to draw with seems very inefficient.

Is there any technique with which I can continuously draw a curve on an HTML5 canvas?

Comment: Your first thought may be the easiest method. Unless you want to emulate the sweep of an O'scope, that may be only slightly more difficult... Are you wanting to just show a sine wave in it's basic form, or are you wanting to also emulate various frequencies?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw a curve that could move to left with canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032998/how-to-draw-a-curve-that-could-move-to-left-with-canvas)

Comment: @Duncan: I'm only interested in showing the sine wave in its basic form. But I would like to learn enough to one day be able to make it more interactive.

Comment: @insertusernamehere: After looking over that post, I do believe that one of the answers there indeed answers my question, making this a duplicate. Sorry about that - I thought I had searched thoroughly, but apparently I can do better.

Comment: @MWinstead Don't worry, took me some time to find it, too. So, If this is helpful and you can work with it, then that's a good thing. :)