# Animated wire in html/css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

For my website I'm in need of an animated wire. It's part of a balloon and must have a sort of winding effect. Is there any easy way of doing this with HTML,CSS or javascript? It is also important that is visible on as much as possible browsers. I already looked at SVG but this looks too complex for only a very little part of the website.

Comment: Here is someone that uses a `canvas`element to draw a sine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032998/how-to-draw-a-curve-that-could-move-to-left-with-canvas   Check out this fiddle and have a look if it suits your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/HhGnb/216/. If you are nor willing to put much afford in it, a animated GIF is maybe your best bet, as it is supported by almost every browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as it hurts, I am recommending an animated gif.

I'd put the balloon and wire in the same animated gif to ensure the two objects don't get 'detached' if the user changes the text size / browser zoom (CTRL +/-)

Answer (score 0):

just use a div and style it like that:

```
width:3px;
height:300px;
background-color: #f0dbc0;
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(35deg, transparent, transparent 5px, #87530f 5px, #87530f 15px);
```

Then you would just need to add some rotation to that div and some horizontal movement with js. That's it.

already looks like a rope if you just paste it :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make the wire interactive use [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/)